# Why is it impossible to resize a vector of thread specific pointers?

Tags: c++, boost-thread

The following works just fine:

```
std::vector<boost::thread_specific_ptr<std::unordered_map<int, int>>> v(1);
```

while the following result in a compilation error:

```
std::vector<boost::thread_specific_ptr<std::unordered_map<int, int>>> v;
v.resize(1);
```

Why is that?

Comment: `boost::thread_specific_ptr` is noncopyable

Comment: Let me see if I understand this correctly. In the second case, `resize` calls the default constructor for `thread_specific_ptr` and then calls the copy constructor `n` times to populate the vector. And since `thread_specific_ptr` are non-copyable, I get the compilation error. Is this correct? But isn't this what happens in the first case too?

Comment: @PaulBaltescu _'But isn't this what happens in the first case too?'_ No, the 1st case doesn't imply copying, while the second might do.

Comment: Looks like the answer to me, gents.